# Webpage practice

Tags: html, css

I have been learning HTML + CSS via online courses like codeacademy and W3schools. I have a very simple grasp as to creating webpages and I want to play in a "sandbox" by creating pages and just messing with stuff.

I'm looking for somewhere I can type in my HTML and CSS and have it display on a webpage just like any other page I look at. I haven't been able to find anything quiet like that, other than the courses themselves. Is there even such a thing?

Comment: For pure CSS and HTML, just save the file on your desktop and open it with a browser

Comment: Have you seen JsFiddle, CodePen, JsBin, etc?

Comment: Unfortunately, *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* You should check out the pinned articles in the [help] for more info on what types of questions are and aren't allowed.

Comment: An example of using codepen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rq9xm0knOXQ

Answer (score 2):

You could try [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)
It accepts JS, HTML, CSS and renders it realtime...

Answer (score 2):

You can download a coding software [such as Brackets](http://brackets.io/).  Save your html file as index.html and your css as styles.css (per example) in the same folder.
Simply click on them in your computer's documents and it should work, opening in your default browser.  You don't need an "online" tool for html/css.

Also check out [this blog post](http://1stwebdesigner.com/free-coding-software/) for alternatives

Comment: Added link on the answer.
Also check out this blog post for alternatives: http://1stwebdesigner.com/free-coding-software/

Comment: I saw. and plus oned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend http://codepen.io. I find it the most user friendly of the bunch

Comment: What makes it the best? Probably? If you can edit your anwser and improve it that would be grand :)

Comment: haha, an improvement but can you state *why* it's the most user friendly? I know it veres towards opinion but a single sentence review would help visitors decide if it's for them :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) would work for what you want.  It also allows you to incorporate javascript as you begin to branch out. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co) is also something I would recommend as it has a "live preview" where your page will automatically display as changes are made.

Answer (score 0):

Get a free website from a site like 000webhost. Then, you can upload and edit code in real time on the server and view it on eg. http://example.freehost.com and you can view it real time. Also you could use software like notepad++ and edit your code before uploading it. Make sure your homepage is index.html